# destructuring a generic type in order to return an objects property

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

say i have a function which takes a lambda function as a parameter to access/return properties of an object, is there a way for the generic to be destructured (perhaps recursively?) so i know if that property exists? i would prefer not to extend T to any existing type as i would like to keep this functions input types as general as possible

heres an example for clarification:

```js
const binarySearch = <T, U>(array:T[], value:(T|U), getProperty?:(item:T, index?:number) => U):number => {}
```

where "U" could be any one of "T"s properties

and which is called either by acessing a property using a lambda if it is an object array

```js
const index = binarySearch(objectArray, objectProperty, (obj) => obj.property)
```

or by using the array value if it isnt

```js
const index = binarySearch(primitiveArray, primitive)
```

im expecting the function to behave as a normal binary search method with more versatility as to not have to make several similar functions to access different property types (especially if those properties are nested)

Comment: please provide an example of usage and what you expect. WHy item is `T|U` ?

Comment: @captain-yossarianfromUkraine ya sry, i rushed through naming variables and thouroughness of the example but i hope my edits cleared some things up. also, T|U is because i want to be able to search for both for a value or an object property depending on the array

Comment: Please provide an example with actual values, I need it for tests

Comment: Please consider providing a self-contained [mre] which demonstrates your issue when pasted, as-is, into a standalone IDE.  Right now my IDE doesn't know what `objectArray`, `objectProperty`, `primitiveArray`, or `primitive` are, so I have to try to fix those just to get started on a solution.  If you could fix those in advance, and provide known use cases others can test against, it will make it more likely that you get a good answer.  If you do [edit] this into the question and want me to take another look, please comment and mention @jcalz so I'm notified.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i ended up finding my own solution while working on some other functions.

the getnestedkeys type function does not have support for nested arrays, because i dont have any application for it, but could probably be implemented as a second ternary after the check of whether the property type is an object

however i still prefer to have the getproperty parameter be conditional just to not have to always type out i => i for any calls dealing with primitive arrays, but this could easily be changed

here is my code:

```js
export type getNestedKeyTypes<T extends object> = {
    [K in keyof T]:T[K] extends object ? getNestedKeyTypes<T[K]> : K[keyof K]
}[keyof T]

export const binarySearch = <T, U, V = T extends object ? getNestedKeyTypes<T> : T>
(arr:T[], value:V, getProperty?:(item:T) => (U&V)):number => {
    if(arr.length === 0) return -1
    const getArrayValue = (i:number) => getProperty ? getProperty(arr[i]) : arr[i]
    const getIndex = (upper:number, lower:number):number => {
        if(lower > upper) return -1
        const m = Math.round((upper+lower)/2)
        const av = getArrayValue(m)
        if(value === av) return m
        if(value > av) return getIndex(m-1, lower)
        return getIndex(upper, m+1)
    }
    return getIndex(0,arr.length-1)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to treat primitives as a special case. In those cases just pass the identity function for `getProperty`: `i => i`.

I'm intrigued enough by your objective to work out a general solution myself, with example usages for 1) an array of numbers as well as 2) an array of objects with a date property:

```
const binarySearch = <T, U>(
  arr: T[], 
  getProperty:(item:T) => U, 
  searchedValue: U, 
  subArrayHeadIndex = 0, //for internal use w/recursion
): number | undefined => {
  const midPoint = Math.floor(arr.length / 2);
  const item = arr[midPoint];
  const propVal: U = getProperty(item);
  if(propVal === searchedValue){
    return subArrayHeadIndex + arr.indexOf(item);
  }
  const newStart = propVal > searchedValue ? 0 : midPoint + 1;
  const newEnd = propVal > searchedValue ? midPoint : arr.length;
  if (newStart === newEnd){
    console.log("couldn't find it")
    return -1
  }
  const newSubArrayHeadIndex = subArrayHeadIndex + (propVal > searchedValue ?  0: midPoint + 1);
  return binarySearch(arr.slice(newStart, newEnd), getProperty, searchedValue, newSubArrayHeadIndex);
}
```

1. Primitives case -- find the position of 29 in the following array:

```
const numbers = [2, 3, 6, 11, 13, 29, 35, 65, 89, 143, 144, 190, 2001];
console.log(binarySearch(numbers, i => i, 29));
// logs "5"
```

2. Object case -- Find the position of the item dated August 21, 1995 from the array:

```
const things = [
  { id: 1, date: 'January 17, 1995 03:24:00'},
  { id: 2, date: 'December 25, 1995 11:24:00'},
  { id: 3, date: 'January 27, 1995 05:43:00'},
  { id: 4, date: 'March 1, 1995 09:44:00'},
  { id: 5, date: 'April 10, 1995 13:20:00'},
  { id: 6, date: 'May 2, 1995 07:16:00'},
  { id: 7, date: 'May 24, 1995 15:55:00'},
  { id: 8, date: 'August 17, 1995 21:33:00'},
  { id: 9, date: 'August 21, 1995 21:49:00'},
  { id: 10, date: 'December 17, 1995 19:57:00'},
];

const getDayString = (dateStr: string) => {
  const date = new Date(dateStr)
  //using Korean here for convenient comparison -- the KR format is "yyyy. mm. dd."
  const d= date.toLocaleDateString("ko-KR", {
    year: "numeric",
    month: "2-digit",
    day: "2-digit"
  });
  return d;
}

console.log(binarySearch(things, i => getDayString(i.date), "1995. 08. 21."))
// logs "8"
```